# Launch internal device storage media from a canvas app

Tags: android, powerapps, power-automate, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula

**Hello guys,**

I have an app that needs to launch some video files from an android device internal storage.

This will be and offline mode situation.

I have tried with launch but did not manage to make it work.

I have even tried to launch VLC player from the canvas app and play a specific video from internal storage
**Launch("vlc: Internal Storage/Media_folder/test_video.mp4")** but it does not work.

Is there a way to do this? I could not find anything.

**Thanks**

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This is it Launch("vlc: Internal Storage/Media_folder/test_video.mp4"), i have VLC installed on the device and it's not working. I don't have anymore code... That simple code should open vlc and play the media from the location.